# Insert record automatically when doing an Insert PL / SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I'm starting to mess with PL / SQL database and I'm having a hard time creating a trigger that when I insert a row into the table, places a value in my column whose name is token.

I made a code with what I know of DB, but when I run it it presents the following error:

> (ORA-04084: can not change NEW values ​​for this type of trigger)

Follow the code:

```
create TABLE table_cad(
codUser integer,
name varchar(200),
pass varchar(50),
login varchar(8),
email varchar(30),
cod number(11)
token number(20));

alter table table_cad add CONSTRAINT codUser_PK PRIMARY key (codUser);

create sequence token_seq
minvalue 1
maxvalue 99999
start with 1
increment by 1;



create or replace trigger token_tgr 
AFTER INSERT ON table_cad

declare
  seq number;
begin
   select token_seq.NEXTVAL
    into sequencial
   from dual;  
  :new.token := seq;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a `BEFORE INSERT`, row-level trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER token_tgr
  BEFORE INSERT ON table_cad
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    SELECT token_seq.NEXTVAL
    INTO   :new.token
    FROM   dual;
END; 
/
```

Comment: tks Kaushik Nayak.